# powershell find which hash table key is contained in a string

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I want to query the operating system name, and will receive results like this:
`Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard` or `Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise`.

I would like to correlate this with arbitrary values like: `SVR2022` and `WIN11`

I tried using a hash table to do so like this:

```
$Version = @{
    'Windows 10' = 'WIN10'
    'Windows 11' = 'WIN11'
    'Server 2022' = 'SVR2022'
    'Server 2019' = 'SVR2019'
    'Server 2016' = 'SVR2016'
    'Server 2012' = 'SVR2012'
    'Server 2008' = 'SVR2008'
}

# Collect info
$os = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem)

# Identify OS Version
$wsusVersion = $Version[($Version.Keys | Where-Object $os.Caption -like "*$($_)*")]
```

This returns a collection with all values in it because I believe `$_` is `$null`.

I've tried a number of different combinations of code, but am having trouble figuring out the most concise and correct way to do this.

Comment: You want `Where-Object {$os.Caption -like "*$($_)*"}` (missing `{ }`)

Comment: Oh geeze. Face palm moment. So focused on the outcome I missed the forest for the trees. Yeah, that fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're missing the `{ }` brackets around your filter expression:

```
($Version.get_Keys() |Where-Object {$os.Caption -like "*${_}*" })
```

Another option is to use the intrinsic `.Where({})` method:

```
($Version.get_Keys().Where({$os.Caption -like "*${_}*"}, 'First')
```

The `First` mode flag will cause `.Where({})` to return as soon as it found a match, preventing you from accidentally resolving multiple labels at once.

If you have a preferred order, make sure you use an ordered dictionary literal instead of a hashtable:

```
$Version = [ordered]@{
    'Windows 10' = 'WIN10'
    'Windows 11' = 'WIN11'
    'Server 2022' = 'SVR2022'
    'Server 2019' = 'SVR2019'
    'Server 2016' = 'SVR2016'
    'Server 2012' = 'SVR2012'
    'Server 2008' = 'SVR2012'
}
```

---

**Note**: The use of `.get_Keys()` rather than just `.Keys` in the example above is deliberate - PowerShell's dictionary adapter prefers key-mapping over .NET members, so if you accidentally fill in an entry with the key `Keys` you'll get unexpected behavior:

```
PS ~> $table = @{ A = 1; B = 2; C = 3; Keys = @('lol') }
PS ~> $table.Keys     # oops
lol
```

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond with the explanation.